# Logical error in code

Tags: error-handling

Code that I am supposed to fill out which was easy enough.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 128
typedef struct {
 char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
 unsigned long sid;
} Student;
/* return the name of student s */
const char* getName(const Student* s) {
 return s->name;
}
/* set the name of student s */
void setName(Student* s, const char* name) {
 /* fill me in */
}/* return the SID of student s */
unsigned long getStudentID(const Student* s) {
 /* fill me in */
}
/* set the SID of student s */
void setStudentID(Student* s, unsigned long sid) {
 /* fill me in */
}
```

However it says what is the logical error in the following function?

```
Student* makeDefault(void) {
 Student s;
 setName(&s, "John");
 setStudentID(&s, 12345678);
 return &s;
}
```

I do not see any problems. I tested it. It works fine.

Is it because this should probably be a void function and does not need to be returning anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a pointer to a locally declared variable (Student s).  The variable "s" will disappear (become garbage) after the return.

Instead, you need to allocate a student first.

You should probably do this:

```
void makeDefault(Student* pS) {
 setName( pS, "John");
 setStudentID( pS, 12345678);
}
```

And then let the calling application allocate the student.